# Calling Vaadin ui (Login page) from HttpServlet class

Tags: jakarta-ee, vaadin7, vaadin4spring

I want to call login page when a user hits a url in the browser. Details are: 
Its a vaadin application, when url is hit it goes to a doGet method of HttpServlet extended class. Now i want to call a login page from this class. Any help for it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. Why do you need a custom servlet class? You typically use Vaadin's default servlet which could open a login page for you. If you absolutely need a custom servlet, you could send a 302 redirect to the client which redirects to the Vaadin servlet which in turn opens the login page.

Comment: There is one link when the user pastes it in the url he should be shown a pdf but if he is not logged in he should get the login page

Comment: Ok, now that use case makes sense. I think this could be solved with a custom RequestHandler. I'll elaborate more on that as soon as I have a bit more time.

Comment: Thanks  RolandKrüger i have solved the issue i am posting the answer to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was rather a simple solution i should have researched a little bit regarding the response.sendRedirect() and i just did not remove the code after this sendRedirect() line and it was throwing error in the next line while calling some function. so lastly removed it and then it redirects to login page by using response.sendRedirect("login"). and i am through it

Thanks  RolandKrüge for your help. :)